# Gitlab: CI webhook on merge request trigger on create and update only

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to run some job for CI in gitlab on merge request.

I have created a webhook and a trigger, and webhook fires on *Merge request events*

[image]

This trigger is fired twice: on create and on merged.

I don't want that trigger is fired on merged, since for me is useless.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Joao Vitorino answer.
After receiving the json data through the webhook you can make the decision based on the value of "action". You can find it in the "object_attributes" object.

```
"object_attributes": {
    "assignee_id": 20,
    "author_id": 20,
    "created_at": "2018-09-04 09:39:25 UTC",
    "description": "blub\\r\\nblub2",
    "head_pipeline_id": null,
    "id": 85,
    "iid": 3,
    "last_edited_at": "2018-09-04 09:50:21 UTC",
    "last_edited_by_id": 20,
    "merge_commit_sha": "035683abb9eae299399210ddd79a0f3b93bc4bbd",
    "merge_error": null,
    "merge_params": {
        "force_remove_source_branch": "0"
    },
    "merge_status": "can_be_merged",
    "merge_user_id": null,
    "merge_when_pipeline_succeeds": false,
    "milestone_id": null,
    "source_branch": "sourceBranch",
    "source_project_id": 34,
    "state": "merged",
    "target_branch": "develop",
    "target_project_id": 34,
    "time_estimate": 0,
    "title": "Feature/olatce 11380",
    "updated_at": "2018-09-04 09:50:25 UTC",
    "updated_by_id": 20,
    "url": "url-to-gitlab.com",
    "source": {
    },
    "target": {
    },
    "last_commit": {

    },
    "work_in_progress": false,
    "total_time_spent": 0,
    "human_total_time_spent": null,
    "human_time_estimate": null,
    "action": "merge"
},
```

It's the last field in the object and can have the following values:

- open (for newly created merge requests)
- update (for updated MR, new commits in source branch or edits of the MR)
- reopen
- close
- merge

With this, you should be able to decide how to handle the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

As I remember in my case the push event works fine

https://{$jenkins.url}/git/notifyCommit?url=ssh://git@gitlab.ing.net:2222/{$group}/{$project}.git

Answer (score 0):

As the option say

> This URL will be triggered when a merge request is **created/updated/merded**

The url is triggered with a json. Use this json to identify in what conditions you should accept the trigger.

Here the [doc's](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#merge-request-events)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin) for this.

If you configure these variables:

- `MR_OBJECT_KIND`  as `$.object_kind`
- `MR_ACTION` as `$.object_attributes.action`
- `MR_OLD_REV` as `$.object_attributes.oldrev`

And a filter text as: `$MR_OBJECT_KIND $MR_ACTION $MR_OLD_REV`

Filter expression as: `^merge_request\s(update\s.{40}$|open.*)`

Then the job should only trigger when created or updated.

There is a complete test case for this here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd/gitlab/gitlab-mergerequest.feature